# Montgomery Reduction form using OpenSSL library

Tags: cryptography, openssl, montgomery-multiplication

I have N of 1024 bits. I need to convert a message M ( 512 bits ) into Montgomery reduction form as below.

M' = M * R^{-1} mod N

where , R = 2 ^ 512 (mod N)

How can I achieve the result ?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work if you use the bignum package from OpenSSL directly.

Use the function `BN_mod_exp` to calculate your R=2^512 (mod N).

Afterwards you calculate the multiplicative modulo inverse of R by calling `BN_mod_inverse`. This will give you the R^-1.

Once done you just calculate your M' by calling `BN_mod_mul` to do the multiplication using your just calculated R^-1 and your original message.

You'll find the functions mentioned above in the OpenSSL BigNum Package. They are located in the include file: openssl/bn.h

Comment: I did exactly the same. However, I am getting R & R^-1 as 1. Is it correct ? I am unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: Can you post your prime N?

Comment: Thanks.. It worked.. I changed the Initialization of BIGNUM structure.

Comment: @user3648560 Congratulations!

Comment: Thank You. Still I am not able to get the actual task done. Do you have any idea regarding "Brumley Time Attack on RSA".

Comment: Yes, I have (it is actually quite easy to perform this attack, you just have to measure the time of your operations and correlate them with the 1 bits in N). However, this was not part of this question. You may find better help for such things at: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It would be great if you could help me out. I have already asked it at below [link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20009/timing-attack-on-openssl-by-brumley). However, no answer yet.